# Switching from prototype to jquery in Rails, what about helpers?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, prototypejs

I currently switching from prototype to jquery mainly to support simple ajax file upload. I use : https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails

95% of javascript code is made by rails helper such as :

```
- remote_function
- render :update do |page|
- page.replace_html 'id', :partial => 'content'
- page['form']['name'] = something
- page.visual_effect :highlight, 'head_success'
...
```

I understand that the 5% of code purely prototype I have to rewrite it for Jquery, but what about the rest ? Do I have to rewrite it all in raw jquery ?

I use :

- Rails 3.0.7
- jquery-rails 1.0.7

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out? Also, there's no need to switch everything over if you don't have to. Both Prototype and jQuery can exist in the same page, though I agree it's better to have only one.

Comment: Huumm, you think it's a good idea to have both ? For the moment, I have tried and I do not have find a way to make this helpers working with jquery.

Comment: I'm not saying it's a _good idea_, but it's not a _bad idea_ either. And it will let you keep working on the project rather than messing around trying to get Rails to do what you want. Also, RJS is bad. I suggest you stop writing it if possible.

Comment: jQuery and Prototype coexist quite well on the same page. However to achieve this, the jQuery core and all other jQuery plugins must be included before the Prototype core.

Comment: Are you saying that is not a good thing to use this helpers ? I just want to cry now... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

all that helpers are deprecated in favor of unobtrusive javascript (it doesn't matter if
you're using jQuery or PrototypeJS).

you can find a detailed guide here:

http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/

Answer (score 0):

The jrails plugin/gem converts the rails prototype helpers (like page.replace_html, page.visual_effect) to use jquery instead of prototype.  Use that and you won't have to change any of your code, except the pure prototype code as you say.

http://mirror.ozdiy.com/assets/b8/2f96a12bc919b37e09d303b86ea1b9_1251811910.html

https://github.com/aaronchi/jrails/

Comment: it seems a little outdated, no ?

Comment: Do you mean there's a better solution since it came out?  If so, what?

Comment: Ooo, no. I just means it doesn't work with rails 3, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery-rails gem has a rake :install task that when run updates the rails.js helper and replaces prototype.js with jquery.js

Comment: Do you have a link to documentation about it? Right now that would be perfect for me